# Откуда очевидность расположения обьектов классов в свободной памяти?

Tags: c++

Привожу отрывок из учебника Страуструпа:

```
class Date2 {
public:
    // могут быть виртуальные функции
protected:
    // ...
private:
    //...
};
```

> Чтобы сделать замещение функций, устанавливающих значение, легким и
>   эффективным, представление обьявлено защищенным. Благодаря этому,
>   класс `Date2` полностью готов к созданию производных классов. Однако
>   цена этого такова:
>    - ...
>    - Требуется использовать свободную память. Цель введения `Date2` -    позволить использовать обьекты разных классов, производных от него,
>   взаимозаменяемым образом. Поскольку размеры этих производных классов
>   различны, очевидно следует распологать их в свободной памяти и
>   обращаться к ним через указатели и ссыльки.
>    - ...

Вопрос касается последнего предложения - откуда очевидность расположения их в свободной памяти? Допустим я напишу производный класс и функцию получающую указатель на базовый класс:

```
class H_Date : public Date2 {
private:
    bool g;
    string s;
    //...
public:
    //...
};
void f(Date2* p) {
    //...
}
```

Что же мешает не использовать свободную память и использовать прямую адресацию? Например так:

```
H_Date obj;   
f(&obj);
```

Comment: Я несколько раз прочитал цитату и не понял сути, можно ссылку на книгу или название? Может это ошибки перевода?

Comment: А Вы разве не обращаетесь к ним через указатель ? И не размещаете его в свободной памяти ?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan книга? Год? Глава?

Comment: @vegorov, свободная область это динамическая память, а тут все в локальной обласи

Comment: @Croessmah,  год 1998, глава  25. 2.1

Comment: @goldstar_labs, вот и я не понел тоже.  год 1998, глава 25. 2.1, переведен на русский. Может перевод неправильный, не знаю

Comment: В оригинале: ```The need to use free store. The aim of Date2 is to allow objects of different classes derived from Date2 to be used interchangeably. Because the sizes of these derived classes differ, the obvious thing to do is to allocate them on the free store and access them through pointers or references. Thus, the use of genuine local variables dramatically decreases.```

Comment: ну и просто вопрос из интереса, с чем связано чтение старого издания? :)

Comment: @Croessmah, я просто  плохо знаю  английский и читал все что попадалось на русском.  В данный момент просто просматриваю  все что раньше читал, тоже ради интереса... И спасибо за ответ - теперь все понятно

Comment: http://www.stroustrup.com/oopsla.pdf - линк на оригинал стр 8

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я английский вообще не знаю. )))

Comment: прочитал оригинал и опять ннп. @ARHovsepyan, вам понятно, объясните теперь мне)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, имеется ввиду,  что  контейнеры  указателей на базовый класс  приходится заполнять обьектами из динамической памяти. Что то типа такого